# JFrame doesn't update its content

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt

I've been struggling to get my JFrame to repaint its content. I've tried using both the revaluate() and repaint() methods together after I add the new components into the JFrame but I'm not seeing the frame change.

Here's the simple GUI of a minesweeper game I'm trying to make.
[image]

When a user clicks on either of the top 3 buttons, they enter the following code block

```
private void drawGrid()
{
        removeAll();

        setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
        add(new JButton("button"));

        setVisible(true);

        revalidate();
        repaint();
        setVisible(false);
        setVisible(true);
}
```

When clicking a button, the whole application turns white, but I can't see the new button I added. When I remove the two setVisible() method lines, then clicking a button definitely removes the components since I can't click on any of them now, but the 4 initial buttons are still visible. Removing the revalidate or repaint methods has no effect on the application.

What else can I try to get the application to refresh and display its new content.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `removeAll` on a `JFrame` is dangerous and can produce unexpected results, another reason why it's discouraged to extend from or manage UI's directly on top level containers.

Start by using a `JPanel` as you base UI component, then use a [`CardLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) to manage switching between the views.

Separate each view into it's own class (extending from `JPanel` or something simular) for easier management

Comment: I tried Creating a JPanel and then inserting all the menu buttons into that panel and then adding the JPanel to the main JFrame, but the GUI  shows up as the 4 buttons squeezed into a 2x2 grid in the top half of the JFrame, even though I've set the layout of the JPanel to be a 4x1 grid

Comment: how could I insert all button into a separate JPanel, and then add the JPanel to the main JFrame, and visually have the same result as I currently have.

Comment: Make sure that the `JFrame` has a layout set to `BorderLayout`, make sure that the "menu" panel has a layout set to `GridLayout`, with 1 column and 0 rows.  You menu doesn't need to have separate panels, it's fine for them to be managed on a single panel, your game view, for example, should be a separate panel, then you can more easily manage the code, rather then trying to dynamically generate the objects on the fly all the time from a single class

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would work better if you used this

```
easyBtn.setVisible( false );
medBtn.setVisible( false );
hardBtn.setVisible( false );
customBtn.setVisible( false );
newBtn.setVisible( true );
```

If that does not work, try putting it into a SwingWorker.